# Avoid a cycle output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to check if there is a cycle in output?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE packages 
(
 request varchar(10), 
 depend varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO packages
(request, depend)
VALUES
('R001', 'R990'),
('R001', 'R992'),
('R002', 'R991'),
('R002', 'R990'),
('R990', 'R001'),
('R010', 'R001'),
('R215', 'R001'),
('R990', 'R887'),
('R990', 'R886');

SELECT
  request,
  depend
FROM
(
  SELECT request, depend FROM packages WHERE request = 'R001'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT request, depend FROM packages WHERE depend IN ('R001')
) as Report
```

http://rextester.com/XLP60912

The final result are:

```
     request     depend
1    R001        R990
2    R001        R992
3    R990        R001
4    R010        R001
5    R215        R001
```

The line 3 is a cycle from line 1, so line 3 should not be in the result.

Expected result:

```
     request     depend
1    R001        R990
2    R001        R992
3    R010        R001
4    R215        R001
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the expected result

Comment: You have to use [recursive query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: are you considering only cycles of size 1? or can be larger cycles?

Comment: Hi Juan. Not sure about what are you asking, but its N ~ N. I can have N requests to N depends and it can be duplicated, triplicated and so on

Comment: In your example cycle are `A->B->A` or like Gordon call it `Swapped Pairs` or can be longer `A->B->C->D->A` then you need a recursive query

Comment: Well, I am looking for a way to bring all the line that has `R001` from the column `request` or `depend`, but (this is the point) If in line 1 there is a R001 - R990, I don't wanna see a R990 - R001 in the result

Comment: Then try Gordon solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for swapped pairs (as in your example), then this will work:

```
select p.request, p.depend
from packages p
where p.request < p.depend or
      not exists (select 1
                  from packages p2
                  where p2.request = p.depend and p2.depend = p.request
                 );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks. I tried, but i need to pass a value in query, so i am looking for `R001`. Tried to change to: `where request = 'R001' and (p.request < p.depend or...)` without success. Clue? Thanks again,

Comment: add `WHERE p.request = 'r001' or p.depend = 'r001'`

Comment: Thanks, Juan. Tried but this is bring lines that do not have `R001`. See: http://rextester.com/FSSQ41498

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
request,
depend
FROM
Packages
Where depend not in(select distinct               request from packages)
```

Comment: Thanks karan. Tried this but I need to pass a value like `R001` in query.

Comment: So you will give the values of request and depend and eliminate the matching